# How to Inject a Client Channel Sink when using Cross-App-Domain remoting (or otherwise fix my problem)

Tags: c#, appdomain, .net-remoting

[In a previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147500), I had problems with LogicalCallContext data that was not and should not be serializable and which was wreaking havoc with remoting calls.  I solve the problem by implementing a client channel sink to strip out the call context data.  I now have a virtually identical problem, except that the remoting call is being made to another AppDomain within the same process, using the classic code for this that looks like so:

```
var remoteDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("SomeDomain", null, appDomainSetup);
var serviceProxy = (IMyService)remoteDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(serviceType.Assembly.FullName, serviceType.FullName);
```

An additional caveat to the current problem is that the call data is being placed on the context by the client assembly that is using my code, so I don't have any control over it being there or not.

The crux of the current problem then is that, to my knowledge, the channel sink chain used for cross-app-domain remoting is hard coded into .Net.  Consequently, there is no way to inject the CallContextSaninitization sink that I developed as the solution to original problem.

So does anyone know of a better way to solve the original problem, or a way to inject a client channel sink when using cross-AppDomain remoting?

Comment: I guess I'm missing something from both your previous and current questions - why are you putting something in the CallContext when you don't seem to want to share it across any remoting channels?

Comment: @Damien, Your statement that I don't want to share it across _any_ remoting calls is incorrect.  In my first post, I need to share it across some, and cannot share it across others.  In the second post, I am not the one putting the data on the call context, but I do need to make a remote call, and the data that the client put on the context is not serializable.